# Structured Array in Powershell batch file adds extra space

Tags: arrays

I have a batch file that contains a structured array.  The problem is that it is adding a space to the end of the variable.  The code below will output:
Name=Joe  zzzzzz
Value=1 zzzzzz
...

Where is the space after the name and value coming from, and how can I get rid of it?
Thanks!

```
@echo off
set len=3 
set obj[0].Name=Joe 
set obj[0].ID=1
set obj[1].Name=Mark
set obj[1].ID=2 
set obj[2].Name=Mohan 
set obj[2].ID=3 
set i=0 
:loop 

if %i% equ %len% goto :eof 
set cur.Name= 
set cur.ID=

for /f "delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in ('set obj[%i%]') do (
   set cur.%%k=%%l 
) 
echo Name=%cur.Name%zzzzzz
echo Value=%cur.ID%zzzzzz
set /a i=%i%+1 
goto loop
```

Comment: this isnt powershell its batch. There is no such thing as powershell batch. I would advise personally to move away from batch all togather and rewrite this in powershell

Comment: I think I am going to take that advice

Comment: Do you want me to rewrite this in powershell to help guide you or are you ok?

Comment: Yes, that would save me hours! Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what the output you would like to see is?

Comment: I would be happy to compensate you for this if that is allowed.  I have config files that need to be altered, and then copied to an aws ec2 instance

Comment: well i was only going to rewrite this example you gave as to give you a starting point

Comment: I would be happy to compensate you for this if that is allowed.  I have config files that need to be altered, and then copied to an aws ec2 instance. This is very rough, but might give you an idea...
do (
 call git checkout configs_%%D
 call aws s3 cp s3://mightyconfigs.hamlethub.com/conf*.* "C:\git\configs\configs_%%D.name\"
 call aws s3 cp s3://folder/ "C:\git\configs\configs_%%D.name\mightyconfig\"
 call FART -V -i "configuration*.php" .hamlethub.com .%%D.com
 \cygwin64\bin\scp.exe -i "C:\cygwin64\key.pem" \Users\Ken\%%%D.name ec2-user@ec2-%%D.ip.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/vendor/*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182688/discussion-between-hamlethub-and-arcset).